# A surface is minimal if and only if there exist two orthogonal asymptotic lines at each of its point

Tags: differential-geometry

I have to solve the following exercise:

"A surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is minimal if and only if there exist two orthogonal asymptotic lines at each of its point"

Recall that an asymptotic line is a smooth curve $\sigma: I \to S$ such that $Q(\sigma'(t))=0$ for every $t \in I$.

Assume first that $S$ is minimal (so that $k_2=-k_1$).

First case: $k_1=0$. Then the point $p$ is planar. At a planar point, all tangent vectors are asymptotic directions. Just take two orthogonal vectors in the tangent plane. **How to conclude that there exist two asymptotic lines? - I have only the tangent in the point $p$, but who ensures me that it gives rise to an asymptotic line?**

Second case: $k_1 \neq 0$. Then using Euler's formula we have $k_n=k_1(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))=0$. Recall that $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$ is the angle from the principal direction $e_1$ to $v$. In the previous case, the equality holds because we considered an asymptotic line (and hence the corresponding asymptotic direction in the point $p$). We get $\theta=\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$.**Is it sufficient to prove that in $p$ we can construct two orthogonal asymptotic lines? Why?**

I have problems with the converse. Assume that there exist two orthogonal asymptotic lines at each of the points of $S$. Fix a point $p \in S$. Then I consider the two asymptotic directions. Denote by $\theta$ and $\alpha$ the corresponding angles with the principal direction $e_1$. Then we have $\theta-\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus, we get

1. $k_1\cos^2(\alpha)+k_2\sin^2(\alpha)=0$
2. $k_1\cos^2(\theta)+k_2\sin^2(\theta)=0$

At this point, I cannot continue. In fact, replacing $\theta$ with $\alpha+\frac{\pi}{2}$, I get the system

1. $k_1\cos^2(\alpha)+k_2\sin^2(\alpha)=0$
2. $k_2\cos^2(\alpha)+k_1\sin^2(\alpha)=0$

Various possibilities arise. **Can you help me, please?**

These are all my troubles. Is it possible to receive a complete answer, clarifying all these points, please?

Comment: Actually, the argument you gave assumes $k_1\ne 0$, does it not? For the converse, write down Euler’s formula for the two different angles; what do you get?

Comment: $k_1(cos^2 \theta - cos^\alpha)=k_2(\sin^2 \alpha - \sin^2\theta)$          but I do not see how to proceed

Comment: However, drawing the picture, it seems that $\theta-\alpha=90°$. So I may replace in the formula. But this gaves me either $k_1=k_2$ or $\theta=\pm 45°$

Comment: You have thrown away valuable information. You should have two equations, not one.

Comment: Not clear, sorry. Can you help me in a more detailed way, please?

Comment: Where is the statement that each of these angles gives $k_n=0$?

Comment: My equality comes from Euler's formula for the two angles. Equating I get the relation you see in my first comment. There I have two angles $\theta$ and $\alpha$. Note that I get the equality by using both the two conditions of $k_n=0$. If necessary, I will edit my question.

Comment: You are making an elementary mistake and not stopping to think about my direct comments. Is the  equation $x=y$ equivalent to the two equations $x=0$ and $y=0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin You're comments are troubling me. You're right on the mistake and I'm verry sorry. I'll correct it. However, I need a complete answer for each to the previous questions. Please, can you help me to solve the doubts?